# xna wp7-trying to get a texture2d from photoChooser

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

in my optionMenuScreen the user picked a poto and then pressed back to the mainMenu and then playGame.

when i'm trying to get the photo in the gamePlayScreen after pressing the back button, its null again.

```
OptionsMenuScreen photo = new OptionsMenuScreen();
        PhotoTexture = new Texture2D(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, 50, 50);
       PhotoTexture= photo.photoRecieved;
       PhotoTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, photo.PhotoResult.ChosenPhoto);
        PhotoPosition = new Vector2(650f, 150f);
```

1. do i have to go straight to the next screen without back button or do you have another solution? what can i do to make it work?
2. how to enable the user to crop the picture as he wishes to the size i define?

help!!!
 thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [xna wp7 how to let the user crop his photo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847081/xna-wp7-how-to-let-the-user-crop-his-photo)

Answer (score 0):

Please include the code for the Photo Chooser; you haven't actually included the code that is your issue, which is why your having this problem :-)

Check that you haven't actually disposed the photo that was taken; in this scenario you can just test with a static variable to hold the texture between the two classes.