# xna wp7 how to let the user crop his photo

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

hi
how can i let the user to crop his picture before choosing one
in the photoChooserTask?
( in msdn it says that the pixelheight/width doesn't work yet)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do the pixel operations yourself after the image has selected. You can render the image to the screen, and then look for two touch points to determine the x/y and height/width ... then create a new texture with those dimensions and render to it as a RenderTarget. You can then save this new texture, or do whatever you need to do with it

Comment: but i need the user to choose his face. please answer only if you know. thanks

Comment: the chooser task, and cropping are two separate operations. You have to allow the user to select or take the photo (this operation is limited by OS functionality) ... once the chooser has completed, it provides the image's data to you as a stream. You can take that stream and put it into a texture, which you can then create a UI to let the user select the dimensions that he'd like to crop to.

Comment: ok thanks and do you have an idea how do i do that? do  u have a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Windows Phone 7 can handle RenderTargets but if it can. You can just have the user drag a rectangle, create a RenderTarget of that size, and then draw to the RenderTarget using the rectangle as the source rectangle of the image you want to crop.